# Dynamically allocating memory for array's elements

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a two-dimension array of custom data type, say something like

```
struct element_t ** arr
```

How do I allocate space for this array's single elements (arr[i][j] ) using malloc()? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
struct element_t **arr;

arr = malloc(N * sizeof(*arr));
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    arr[i] = malloc(X * sizeof(*arr[i]));
}
```

Where N is the size of your double array and X the size of each array;

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to allocate memory. If you want a contiguous chunk of memory then

```
arr = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*arr));
arr[0] = malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(struct element_t));
for(int i = 1; i < nrows; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[0] + i * ncolumns;
```

For non contiguous

```
arr = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*arr));
for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(struct element_t));
```

For detailed explanation read [How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)